# Can't login with iCloud Control Panel for Windows. Constant server error

Tags: network, icloud, windows

I have problem of connecting to iCloud with iCloud Control panel for Windows.
After a while it errors with can't connect because of server error. And gives me a link to iCloud status which is always all green.

This problem is not last hour problem, it is constantly the same from the time I installed iCloud CP version 4 when it was released. I didn't have previous version of CP installed on this machine. I did't tweaked services above usual turn off of XPS server and Tablet PC components in Programs (Unistall part of Windows Control Panel)

I have Windows Firewall enabled (though disabling it doesn't make a change). Antivirus is MSSE. I am behind old Linksys router though it has uPNP enabled on it (and disabling SPI firewall on it doesn't change anything either). It is in Gateway mode.
Itunes login into account fine and I can log into iCloud.com with a browser.

Windows is Windows 7 Ultimate 32bit on Athlon XP (not SSE2 capable, had to mention because some apps just forget there are such processors still in use)
Version of iCloud CP is the last 4.0.2 (at the moment of writing).

If anybody does know what I can do to trouble shoot it I would be happy to hear. And yes I've already removed and installed iCloud CP few times. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. Turning off all antivirus temporarily and firewall seemed to fix it